# How do I add a sentinel value to my code?

Tags: java, arrays, sentinel

When the user enters 0, the program is supposed to stop. I can't figure out  how to do this. For example:
Enter the integers between 1 and 100: 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2 0
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 time
4 occurs 1 time
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs 1 time
23 occurs 1 time
43 occurs 1 time

My code prints the 0.

```
public class CountOccurrences {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter ten integers between 1 and 100: ");
String userInput = input.nextLine(); 

//this splits the user input into an array using a space
String[] inputString = userInput.split(" "); 
String[] previousValues = new String[inputString.length];

int count = 1;  

//Compare elements and update count for new string
  for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
   for (int j = i+ 1; j < inputString.length; j++) {
     if (inputString[i].equals(inputString[j]) && notFound (previousValues, inputString[i]) {                                  `               
      count++;   
    } 
 }

  //Prints only unique strings
  if(!userInput.equals("0")){
    if (notFound(previousValues,inputString[i])) {
      if (count>1) {
        System.out.println(inputString[i] + " occurs " + count + " times");
      } else { 
        System.out.println(inputString[i] + " occurs " + count + " time");
      }
          count = 1;
      }
      if (notFound(previousValues,inputString[i])) {
        previousValues[i] =   inputString[i];
      }
}}


}

//This method returns a boolean value. It is true if the string is not in the array  and vice versa

public static boolean notFound(String[] pastValues, String currentString) {
boolean valueNotFound = true;
int index = 0;
while(index < pastValues.length && valueNotFound) {
  if ((pastValues!= null) &&(currentString.equals(pastValues[index]))) {
    valueNotFound = false;
  }
  index++;
  }
  return valueNotFound;
  }

//Method for printing an array
  public static void printArray(String [] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(a[i]+ "  ");

   }

   }

 }
```

Comment: `if(!userInput .equals("0")) ` after you get the input then nest inside that if all the code that should be executed should do the trick given what you said.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the few minutes it takes to properly format/indent your source code; instead of dropping such a mess here - you see, that code doesn't even compile, as you have  `if(!userInput.equals(0)){` there - missing the quotes around 0!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding an `else` condition and using `System.exit(0)` and tell the user that the program is going to terminate.

> static void   exit(int status) Terminates the currently running program or Java Virtual Machine.

status 0 indicates that the program execution completed without exceptions.

You can look at the API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)